# migration c++ code 32 bit machine to 64 bit machine

Tags: c++, endianness

I am working on very legacy code which is migration to 32 bit to 64 bit machine.it generally write file with data which was working fine in 32 bit but having issue in 64 bit machine.When I check the file and found that it is generally contain division of 4 of 32 bit value. I mean if we have 80 value in 32 bit machine than it will be 20 in 64 bit machine.(most case). I have  looked into below piece of code and could not understand some of functionality.

1. why we call reverse function before write into File.
2. What is purpose of reverse function.
3. In write function,we always write one_ascii value although we have any data type.

I have tried to took some piece of code which help me to explain issue briefly.Please let 
me know if I need to provide more information.

```
class  GdsHeader
{
public:
  unsigned  short  rlen;
  char      record_type;
  char      data_type;
};

class  GdsRecord
{
public:
#ifndef SWIG
  union
    {
    short    *two_int;
    int     *four_int;
    double   *eight_real;
    char     *one_ascii;
//    void    *v;
    };
#endif
  int  length;

      GdsRecord (); // { v = 0; length = 0; }
      ~GdsRecord ()  ;//  { delete v; }
  void  len (int l, int type);
};




    class  GdsBlock
    {
      bool      valid_block ();
      int      len;

    public:

      bool      record_unred;
      int      header_ftell;
      GdsHeader  h;
      GdsRecord  r;
      int      array_size;
    //  bool      re_read;

    //          GdsBlock () { re_read = false; }
              GdsBlock () { record_unred = false; header_ftell = 0; }
      void      set (int rt, int dt, int sz)
                {TBE;
                h.record_type = rt;    h.data_type = dt;
                array_size = sz;       r.len (sz, dt);TBX;
                }
       int      read_header (FILE *);
      void      read_block (FILE *);

      void      write (FILE *);
      void      prt ();
    };



    void  GdsRecord :: len (int l, int type)
{

  switch (type)
    {
    case STREAM_Bit_array:
    case STREAM_Short:  l *= 2; break;
    case STREAM_Long:    l *= 4; break;
    case STREAM_Double:  l *= 8; break;
    }
  if (l > length)
    {
    l = ((l / 8) + 2) * 8;
    if (one_ascii) delete [] one_ascii;
    one_ascii = new char[l];
    debug2.printf("GdsRecord::len  new one_ascii  len %d   one_ascii %X\n",l, one_ascii);
    length = l;
    }

}


#ifndef sparc
        static  void  reverse (int len, char *buf)
        {
          TBE;
          char  tmp[24];
         int  i;
          for (i = 0; i < len; i++) tmp[i] = buf[i];
          for (i = 0; i < len; i++) buf[i] = tmp[ (len - 1) - i];
          TBX;
        }
        inline  void  reverse (int len, short *s)  { reverse (len, (char *) s); }
        inline  void  reverse (int len, int *s)    {  reverse (len, (char *) s); }
        inline  void  reverse (int len, double *s)  { reverse (len, (char *) s); }
        inline  void  reverse (int len, unsigned char *s)  {reverse (len, (char *) s); }
        #endif

void    GdsBlock :: write (FILE *outstr)
{
TBE;
debug.printf("GdsBlock::write %X\n",outstr);
  int  i, err;
  char  *c, tmp;
  if (h.data_type == 3)
  {
      cout<<"Begin...blk.r.four_int[0] =>"<<r.four_int[0]<<endl;
  }
  if (!this)
    error.printf_exit("GdsBlock::write error !this\n");

  if (!outstr)
    error.printf_exit ("GdsBlock::write  Error - outstr == 0\n");

  err = ferror(outstr);
  cout<< __LINE__<<"    "<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<endl;
  if (err)
    { {
    char  *s = strerror (err);
    fclose (outstr);
    error.printf_exit ("GdsBlock::write  error - %s, errno %d\n", s, err);
    }
  switch(h.data_type)
    {
    case 0: /* NO DATA */
      h.rlen = 4;
  cout<< __LINE__<<"    "<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<endl;
      break;
      case 1: /* BIT ARRAY */
  cout<< __LINE__<<"    "<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<endl;
#ifndef sparc
       reverse (2, &r.two_int[0]);
#endif
      h.rlen = (2 * array_size) + 4;
      break;
      case 2: /* TWO BYTE SIGNED INTEGER */
  cout<< __LINE__<<"    "<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<endl;
#ifndef sparc
      for (i = 0; i < array_size; i++)    reverse(2,&r.two_int[i]);
#endif
      h.rlen = (2 * array_size) + 4;
      break;
      case 3: /* FOUR BYTE SIGNED INTEGER */
  cout<< __LINE__<<"    "<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<endl;
#ifndef sparc
      for(i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
      {
          cout<<r.four_int[i]<<endl;
          int *temp = &r.four_int[i];
          reverse(4,temp);
          //print_stacktrace();
          cout<<r.four_int[i]<<endl;
          //r.four_int[i] = r.four_int[i] << 2 ;
      }

#endif
      h.rlen = (4 * array_size) + 4;
      break;
      case 5: /* EIGHT BYTE REAL */
  cout<< __LINE__<<"    "<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<endl;
#ifndef  FPC
        for (i = 0; i < array_size; i++)    getr ((CONV *) (r.eight_real + i));
#endif
#ifdef  FPC
        for (i = 0; i < array_size; i++)    fpc (r.eight_real + i);
#endif
      h.rlen = (8 * array_size) + 4;
      break;
      case 6: /* CHARACTER ARRAY */
  cout<< __LINE__<<"    "<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<endl;
      h.rlen = array_size + 4;
      break;
    default:
      error.printf_exit("Error: bad record type %d in GdsBlock :: external\n", (int) h.data_type);
      }

  if (h.rlen % 2)
    {
    r.one_ascii[h.rlen] = 0;
    h.rlen++;
    }

  cout<< __LINE__<<"    "<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<endl;

  i = h.rlen - 4;
#ifndef sparc
  c = (char *) &h.rlen;
  tmp = c[0];
  c[0] = c[1];
  c[1] = tmp;
#endif
  err = fwrite (&h, 1, sizeof (h), outstr);
  if (err != sizeof(h))
    {
    err = ferror(outstr);
    if (err)
      {
      char  *s = strerror (err);
      fclose (outstr);
      error.printf_exit ("GdsBlock::write  error - %s, errno %d\n", s, err);
      }

    fclose (outstr);
    error.printf_exit("Error: bad header fwrite in GdsBlock :: write\n");
    }
#if 1
  err = fwrite (r.one_ascii, 1, i, outstr);
  if (err != i)
    {
    err = ferror(outstr);
    if (err)
   {
      char  *s = strerror (err);
      fclose (outstr);
      error.printf_exit ("GdsBlock::write  error - %s, errno %d\n", s, err);
      }

    fclose (outstr);
    error.printf_exit("Error: bad record fwrite in GdsBlock :: write\n");
    }
#endif
debug.printf("GdsBlock::write exit\n");
  TBX;
}
```

Comment: Your 3rd question it application specific, and not a C++ question.  You, and/or the one who wrote this code, should know.

Comment: I think After posting the question,I realize it may be endianness issue for 32 bit to 64 bit.Not sure but reading after comment

Comment: Try to build a minimal, compilable example that writes 80 on a 32 bit machine and 20 on a 64 bit machine. With these code fragments, people can only guess at both what the fragments do and at what your actual problem is.

Comment: My guess would be assuming that sizeof(short) = 2 and sizeof(int) = 4, and some havoc with initializing and reading back those unions. Integer division works just fine with 64-bits, anyway -- that's for sure.

Comment: One question if possible,Could anyone tell me. what could be reason to reverse byte before write into file.I am not able to figure out the reason

Answer (score 2):

`reverse()` reverses the byte-order, depending on platform.  Shown here seems to be only the non-SPARC version of `reverse()`  See [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Reason for reversing the byte-order (i.e. calling `reverse()`) before writing to file is to make the file format platform (i.e. endianness) independent.

Comment: Reversing the byte order won't make it endianness independent. Only 8-bit encodings are endianness independent. If there is byte reversal going on, there is endianness.

Answer (score 1):

This is some really awful code. You also made some mistakes in copying it here: you copied `GdsRecord` twice, and the `i` variable in `GdsBlock::write` is not declared.

Anyway, what this seems to be supposed to be doing (and I'm not at all certain that it does the right thing, depending on how `GdsRecord::len` works and what the exact meaning of all these wonderfully under-documented fields and magic numbers is) is write `int`s in big-endian format.

However, it doesn't appear to write `short`s in big-endian, which is weird, because I'm pretty sure this means that it won't work in sparc/x86 interoperability anyway. I'm not sure what endianness sparc uses for `double`s, so that part might or might not work. Also, I can't come up with a reading of `GdsBlock::write` that doesn't write the data only partially if the type isn't `char`.